# Use variables across multiple 'it' statements to track change in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I'm using Cypress (https://www.cypress.io/) to test an app that keeps track of the amount of API calls are done within a user limit. The test checks the limit before the API call and again after a call. Purpose of the test is to see if the limits change after doing a call.

The limit is rendered on screen. And I try to store the value in a variable. After doing the API call I want to compare the value before and after.

Already tried to store it in a variable with const and let, but both don't work outside the 'it' statement.

```
it('should get the limit value before doing an api call', ()=> {
            cy.get('.bar__legend')
                .contains('used')
                .then(($usage) => {
                    let usageTxt = $usage.text()
                    let words = usageTxt.split(' ')
                    let usageBefore = words[0]
                })
        });


it('should do an API call twice', () => {
            // do a API call twice
}

it('should get the limit value after doing an api call', ()=> {
            cy.get('.bar__legend')
                .contains('used')
                .then(($usage) => {
                    let usageTxt = $usage.text()
                    let words = usageTxt.split(' ')
                    let usageAfter = words[0]

                    cy.log(usageBefore)
                    cy.log(usageAfter)
                })
        });
```

Another approach I tried

```
it('should increase the limit after an api call', ()=> {
            cy.get('.bar__legend')
                .contains('used')
                .then(($usage) => {
                    let usageTxt = $usage.text()
                    let words = usageTxt.split(' ')
                    let usageBefore = words[0]
                })

            cy.visit('apilink')
            cy.wait(2000)

            cy.visit('apilink')
            cy.wait(2000)

            cy.get('.bar__legend')
                .contains('used')
                .then(($usage) => {
                    let usageTxt = $usage.text()
                    let words = usageTxt.split(' ')
                    let usageAfter = words[0]

                    cy.log(usageBefore)
                    cy.log(usageAfter)
                })
        })
```

I expected a value for both variables, but the test fails, because the 'usageBefore' variable does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the trick was to define the variable outside the `it()`'s. Thus the syntax would look like this:

```js
var usageBefore
var usageAfter

describe('description of the test', () =>{
  it('This uses the variable', () =>{
    cy.get('.bar__legend')
      .contains('used')
      .then(($usage) => {
        let usageTxt = $usage.text()
        let words = usageTxt.split(' ')
        usageBefore = words[0]
      })
  })
  it('should get the limit value after doing an api call', ()=> {
    cy.get('.bar__legend')
      .contains('used')
      .then(($usage) => {
        let usageTxt = $usage.text()
        let words = usageTxt.split(' ')
        usageAfter = words[0]

        cy.log(usageBefore)
        cy.log(usageAfter)
      })
})
```

Comment: Tried it on different levels in the structure. I can define them on the upper level outside the 'describe' block, but they are not changed by the calls in the 'it' blocks.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. The variables are now declared on a global level and assigning values and getting the values only work inside the cy.get statements.

```
var usageBefore
var usageAfter

describe('User limits', () => {
    context('Check user limits', () => {
        it('should increase the limit after an api call', () => {
             cy.get('.bar__legend')
                .contains('used')
                .then( $usage => {
                    var usageTxt = $usage.text()
                    var words = usageTxt.split(' ')
                    usageBefore = words[0]
                })

            cy.visit('apicall')

            cy.get('.bar__legend')
                .contains('used')
                .then( $usage => {
                    var usageTxt = $usage.text()
                    var words = usageTxt.split(' ')
                    usageAfter = words[0]
                })

            cy.get('.bar__legend')
                .contains('used')
                .then($usage => {
                    expect(usageAfter).to.be.greaterThan(usageBefore)
                })
```

Setup needs a lot of refactoring, but it works. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to refactor your code and move everything under one `it()` block as that's going to be your test case. Also notice that you're duplicating code, so you can either create a custom command for that or just define a function locally (the parts that start with `cy.get('.bar__legend')...` )
Your question is mainly related to variable scopes rather than anything specific to cypress. Take a look at this for better understanding: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: I understand the repetition part, I will fix that later. I tried doing one 'it' block (see above), but then again, the variable is out of scope (because the cy.get is the function). I'm looking for a way to write global variables...

Comment: @EdwartVisser did you get the solution ?